# Can we calculate the approximate TPS (Transactions per second) value that we reach based on Hourly active user count?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, capacity-planning

One of my clients is asking about the expected TPS before the execution. He has given the below requirements to initiate the load test,

**The expected hourly active user count:** 14250 (concurrent)

**The total think time:**  625 Seconds (4 thread groups with different user flows. each flow action controller has 5 Seconds delay)

**No Pace time:** 0

**Total Number of endpoints:** 212 (4 thread groups with different user flows)

Can anyone help me to calculate the approximate TPS (Transactions per second) value that we reach for the above configuration?

Is this data set will sufficient to do this calculation? Appreciate it if anyone can help with this calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not sufficient because you don't know the response time for all 212 endpoints, you can assume what could be the TPS if response time would be 1 second or 2 seconds, but it's not possible to predict the actual TPS without knowing what is the response time.

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

More information: [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)

Comment: @Dimitri Thanks for the valuable response. This resolved my doubts about this calculation.